# Javascript check before saving to a table

Tags: javascript, t-sql

Is it possible in javascript to check if multiple records in a table have certain identical fields, before saving?

Ex.

| article | size_type | adj_type | size_list | quant |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

If the size_type field is equal to 1, the adj_type and / or size_list fields must be the same.
An alert should appear stating “for a size_type there cannot be different add_type and size_list.

It's possible?
Thank you.

Comment: It's possible to do all sorts of things with software. What have you tried?

Comment: unfortunately nothing, I don't know where to start. can you give me an example?

Comment: Where does `tsql` fit into your question? It's a nice enough tag, but seems extraneous.

Comment: the table containing the fields: | article | type_sizes | type_agg | size_list | quant | is present in sql server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing is to pass the data from the table to a data structure. For example in the following example I show a form:

```js
const data = {
    article: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    size_type: [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2],
    adj_type: [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
    size_list: [1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    quant: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
};

const incidents = [];
data.size_type.forEach((value, index) => {
    if (value === 1 && data.adj_type[index] !== 1) {
        incidents.push({ row: index, entry: "adj_type" });
    }

    if (value === 1 && data.size_list[index] !== 1) {
        incidents.push({ row: index, entry: "size_list" });
    }
});

console.log(incidents);
```

The result could fit better, but in this case it shows the index where the issue occurs and the name of the property where it occurs

Update: Regarding passing the table data to a data structure, you can try the following

```js
const rows = document.querySelectorAll("table tbody tr");
const entries = Array.from(rows).map((row) => {
    return Array.from(row.cells).map((cell) => +cell.textContent);
});
const data = {
    article: entries[0],
    size_type: entries[1],
    adj_type: entries[2],
    size_list: entries[3],
    quant: entries[4],
};

console.log(data);
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>article</th>
            <th>size_type</th>
            <th>adj_type</th>
            <th>size_list</th>
            <th>quant</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I have to create a function{ and the values ​​that I can insert in the fields are lists from other tables. So the value 1, 2 are not fields where you can write but are to be selected.

Comment: I'm sorry, I do not understand